# Declaring objects as parameters doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, object

I get a "node not found" (DOM Exception 8) error when I later try to append objects I create with this code:

```
object.addimgs = function(a){
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i][0] = create("img", {position: "absolute"}, {src: a[i][1]});
        }
}
```

The array I'm plugging in for `a` is this:

`[[this.logo, "img/coffee.png"], [this.door, "img/door.png"]]`

So essentially I'm trying to use a for loop to declare objects because it would be more efficient than what I had working before:

```
this.logo = create("img", {position: "absolute"}, {src: "img/coffee.png"});
this.door = create("img", {position: "absolute"}, {src: "img/door.png"});
```

... etc

(`create(a, b, c){` is a custom function, I know the code above works)

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working? Do the objects stop being objects when they're entered in as a parameter?

Comment: could `this` be loosing scope?

Comment: I tried preceding it all with `var me = this;` and using `me.logo`, etc and that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have an `<object>.<property>` in JavaScript, it can either be used to return or set the value. It cannot be used as a pointer. In this case:

```
var o = {}
function setToFoo( v ){ v = "foo" }
setToFoo( o.foo );
console.log( o.foo ); // undefined
```

If you want to assign something dynamically, then you should be using array syntax: `<object>["name"] = #value` and assigning that way:

```
var a = [["logo", "img/coffee.png"], ["door", "img/door.png"]]
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
     this[a[i][0]] = create("img", {position: "absolute"}, {src: a[i][1]});
}
```

If I were building something like your method, however, I would actually be using key=>value mappings in a dynamic object to make it more obvious:

```
object.addimgs = function(obj, src){
   for (var it in src ){
       obj[it] = create("img", {position: "absolute"}, {src: src[it]});
   }
}

var src = {logo: "img/coffee.png", door: "img/door.png"}
var obj = // whatever your "this" is
object.addimgs(src, obj);
```

Comment: Hmmm, I use key=>value maps in my `create()` function to set object styles and all the other attributes, that's a fair point. But did you mean `var it in src` rather than `on`?

Answer (score 2):

I see what you are trying, but assigning to `a[i][0]` will assign to the array slot, not what the array slot contains.

Further, when you create the array like this:

```
[[this.logo, "img/coffee.png"], [this.door, "img/door.png"]]
```

The array element `[0][0]` is not a *reference to* the `this.logo` member as it looks like you are expecting.  The array element `[0][0]` will contain the value of `this.logo` at the time that you create the array, which will most likely be `undefined`.

Try something like this instead:

```
object.addimgs = function(a){
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        a[i][0][a[i][1]] = create("img", {position: "absolute"}, {src: a[i][2]});
    }
}
```

Then call it with this array:

```
[[this, "logo", "img/coffee.png"], [this, "door", "img/door.png"]]
```

Comment: Ah you have it right! I wasn't aware of the reference/value thing. I got it to work with this:  

`this[a[i][0]] = create...` Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: No problem.  Another way to explain it is that your code didn't work for the same reason that `var x = this.logo; x = 42;` doesn't assign 42 to `this.logo`.